# How to get button background image in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, button, background

Currently i am working in iPhone application, I have create two button and set image for both buttons, when the user touch button2 then show button1 image inside button2, i tried my level best, but i can't fix this, please any one help me

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

```
     btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn1.frame=CGRectMake(61, 60, 50, 50);
    [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(Button1Method) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn1];  

    btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn2.frame=CGRectMake(112, 60, 50, 50);
    [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(Button2Method) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn2]; 



-(void)Button2Method
{

 [btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:btn1.currentBackgroundImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:-

```
[btn2 setImage:btn1.currentImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And `currentBackgroundImage` is an `UIImage` and you're treating it as a `NSString` this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
        UIImage *img = btn1.currentImage;
        [btn2 setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are setting image to button `btn1 setImage:` and accessing background image `btn1.currentBackgroundImage`

so change your code **Tested**

```
-(void)Button2Method
{
    [btn2 setImage:btn1.imageView.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```